# How create package in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3

Please need explanation of creating package in laravel 5.3.
i want to create package that give me exact location when input longituate and latitude.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you had a look at the docs? We're not here to write code for you - so tell us what you've found so far and we'll give you a hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proper way of creating package:

Steps:

1.We set up a folder structure for our package.

2.We created a composer file for our package and autoloaded it

3.We created a Service Provider for our package and added it to the existing list in config/app.php

4.We created a controller that contains the logic to get the Developer Status

5.We created a config file that contains our package configurations.

6.We created a routes file to point to our controller

7.We updated our Service Provider to resolve our Controller